# Merge PDF files using iTextSharp into output Stream

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to merge PDF files (potentially 1000s of them) in a streaming fashion so that I don't have to load all documents into memory or create one monster output PDF that is loaded into memory.

For my function, I simply pass it a directory name that contains all the PDFs to merge along with an output `Stream` to write to.

```
private void MergePDFDocuments( string batchFilesFolder, Stream outputStream )
{
    using ( var batchDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document() )
    using ( var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance( batchDocument, outputStream ) )
    {
        batchDocument.Open();

        var cb = writer.DirectContent;

        foreach ( var file in new DirectoryInfo( batchFilesFolder ).GetFiles( "*.pdf" ) )
        {
            // we create a reader for the document
            using ( var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader( file.FullName ) )
            {
                int i = 0;
                while ( i < reader.NumberOfPages )
                {
                    i++;
                    batchDocument.SetPageSize( reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation( 1 ) );
                    batchDocument.NewPage();

                    var page = writer.GetImportedPage( reader, i );
                    var rotation = reader.GetPageRotation( i );

                    if ( rotation == 90 || rotation == 270 )
                    {
                        cb.AddTemplate( page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation( i ).Height );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cb.AddTemplate( page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0 );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get a 'System.ObjectDisposedException Exception: Cannot access a closed file.' exception.  Here is the call stack.

```
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.get_Position()
   at iTextSharp.text.io.RAFRandomAccessSource.Get(Int64 position, Byte[] bytes, Int32 off, Int32 len)
   at iTextSharp.text.io.IndependentRandomAccessSource.Get(Int64 position, Byte[] bytes, Int32 off, Int32 len)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.Read(Byte[] b, Int32 off, Int32 len)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.ReadFully(Byte[] b, Int32 off, Int32 len)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.ReadFully(Byte[] b)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(PRStream stream, RandomAccessFileOrArray file)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(PRStream stream)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream.ToPdf(PdfWriter writer, Stream os)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.WriteTo(Stream os)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Write(PdfIndirectObject indirect, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation, Boolean inObjStm)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddToBody(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReaderInstance.WriteAllPages()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddSharedObjectsToBody()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
   at iTextSharp.text.DocWriter.Dispose()
   at BTR.Evolution.Legacy.Jobs.BatchDocGen.MergePDFDocuments(String batchFilesFolder, Stream outputStream) in C:\BTR\Source\Evolution\BTR.Evolution\Legacy.Jobs\BatchDocGen.cs:line 598
```

Comment: Merging document with `PdfWriter`? That's causes a lot of problems. See [How to merge documents correctly?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly) Also: you are closing the `PdfReader` implicitly. If I were you, I'd move to iText 7 for C# instead of using iTextSharp. Plenty of things have improved when we rewrote iText from scratch.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie From your link, I assume I would use the `PdfSmartCopy` sample? If following that pattern, is the entire output document in memory during creation or is the creation of the document 'streamed' to the output `Stream`?

Comment: iText will try to stream as many pages to the output stream as possible, but you have to use concepts such as freeing the reader instance. Look for the `freeReader()` method. If you don't use this method, all your reader instances will consume plenty of memory.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Didn't see it in any of samples on site, but is it accepted (or better yet, recommended) to call `smartCopy.AddDocument( reader ); smartCopy.FreeReader( reader );` for every file I merge into `PdfSmartCopy smartCopy`?  It seems to be working for my initial tests and I'm hoping that is causing the whole creation process to be streaming and not memory intensive.

Comment: I've added a codereview post at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146713/using-itextsharp-and-adddocument-freereader-to-create-a-pdf-document-in-streamin

Answer (score 0):

I bet your parameter 'outputStream' is closed. Are you calling this method twice?  When your variable 'writer' gets disposed, it'll close the underlying stream.

Comment: I only call the method once.  I tested with directory of 2 documents, and as soon as it hits the end of the `using batchDocument/writer` on the first (and only) time, it throws the exception.

Comment: At first sight, I'd say it's not a problem of the `outputStream`. The error message points in the direction of `PdfReader`. The `PdfReader` is closed before it can be read. The reader objects are closed when the `using` brackets are closed. That's probably too early.